# Data binding with Angular (4.0.0) and Material 2.0.0-beta.8

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, typescript, angular-material

I'm new to Typescript and overall WebDev.
Currently, I want to use md-select to bind data to a form that is submitted to a backend, but my current implementation breaks the page. The HTML looks as follows.

```
<md-input-container class="home__input-container">
 <md-select placeholder="sex | male/female" [(ngModel)]="patient.gender" name="gender">
 <md-option *ngFor="let gender of genders" [value]="gender">
  {{gender}}
 </md-option>
 </md-select>
 </md-input-container>
```

I am importing most possible modules (MdSelect, Forms, etc.) as shared.modules file in appcomponent. The select is used in one of the other components.
Here I define the genders string.

```
public genders: string[] = ["male","female"];
```

Here is the object I want to bind data to.

```
export class Patient {
dose: number = 20;
mass: number = 30;
gender: string = "male";
age: number = 10;}
```

Any suggestions on what's wrong?

Comment: Issue is solved, md-input-container does not work with md-select in Material 2.0.0-beta.8 :)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong on your HTML:

```
<md-input-container class="home__input-container">
  <md-select placeholder="sex | male/female" [(ngModel)]="patient.gender" name="gender">
  <md-option *ngFor="let gender of genders" [value]="gender">
    {{gender}}
  </md-option>
  </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

On your component.ts, you should be using an object, instead of a class for patient. However, you may use an interface (Patient) to define the typings for your `patient` object .

```
interface Patient {
  dose: number;
  mass: number;
  gender: string;
  age: number;
}
```

And within your class itself,

```
genders: string[] = ["male","female"];

patient: Patient = {
  dose: 20,
  mass: 30,
  gender: 'male',
  age: 10,
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it did not fix my problem, it still breaks the page.Is it maybe a problem that I am using it withing a md-card or with angular-flex?

Comment: @GeorgiIvanov Hmm.. May I know what errors are being displayed on the debugger/console? In addition, may i know what versions of angular and material are you using

Comment: ERROR Error: "No value accessor for form control with name: 'gender'" &
ERROR Error: "md-input-container must contain an mdInput directive. Did you forget to add mdInput to the native input or textarea element?"
Title tells about versions (Angular 4.0.0, Material 2.0.0-beta.8).

Comment: @GeorgiIvanov hmm.. are you using reactive forms? This looks like an error from reactive forms itself. Try to remove the `formControlName` attribute! There shouldn't be any of those if you are not planning to use it

Comment: Issue solved! md-input-container does not work with md-select in this version :)